# JScrollPane not appearing on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, jtextarea

I'm trying to add the JScrollPane to my JTextArea, but somehow, it won't appear.
I've tried resizing it according to the dimension of the JTextArea, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, notice that I'm using the null layout because I want the full-on flexibility of displaying certain buttons and panels at a pinpoint location.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PaneTester{

  private static JFrame frame;
  private static JPanel panel;
  private static JScrollPane scrollPane;
  private static JTextArea notificationBox;

  public static void main (String [] args){
    stage1(); 
    stage2();
  }

  private static void stage1(){
    createFrame();
    createPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static void stage2(){
    generateNotificationBox();
  }

  private static void createFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(900,700)); 
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
  }

  private static void createPanel(){
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    generateGridButtons();
  }

  private static void generateGridButtons(){
    short y = 0; 
    for(short i=0;i<4;i++){
      y += 60;
      short x = 500;
      for(short j=0;j<5;j++){
        JButton gridButton = new JButton();
        gridButton.setBounds(x, y,120,60);
        panel.add(gridButton);
        x += 140;
      }
    }    
  }
  public static void generateNotificationBox(){
    notificationBox = new JTextArea(10,10);
    notificationBox.setBounds(25, 25, 200, 400);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(notificationBox, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                 ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS ); 

    Dimension d = new Dimension(notificationBox.getPreferredSize());
    scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(d);
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(notificationBox);
    panel.add(notificationBox);
    panel.repaint();
  }

}
```

Comment: `but there isn't any layout manager that I could use that would ideally perfect the visualization of my program` - nobody suggested to use only a single layout manager. You can nest panels each using a different layout to logically group components. For example your grid of 20 buttons would indicate using a GridLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Stop mucking with `setBounds` and `setPreferredSize`, you're just making live more difficult for your self.

If you want to affect the size of `JTextArea` (and the viewable area of the `JScrollPane`) have a look at the `JTextArea` constructor [`JTextArea(int rows, int columns`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea-int-int-), which will allow you to specify the number of rows/columns you want the `JTextArea` to default to, and which will allow the `JTextArea` to calculate it's `preferredSize` based on the current font's metrics in more stable cross platform way

Your core problem, however, is right here...

```
scrollPane.getViewport().add(notificationBox);
panel.add(notificationBox);
```

You add the `notificationBox` to the `JScrollPane`s `JViewport`, which is good, but then you add `notificationBox` to the `panel`, which will remove it from the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewport`, which is bad

Instead, add the `JScrollPane` to the `panel`

```
scrollPane.getViewport().add(notificationBox);
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

You're also making overuse of `static`. I'd highly recommend you take the time to reduce `static` down to it's absolute minimum required usage, this will probably mean that rather then constructing the UI in the `main` method, you have a "main" class which you can insatiate (from `main`) which will perform the initial setup - IMHO

> I've tried that. I think someone else suggested that from another post, but when I tried that, it just took away the JTextArea completely from the panel

Get rid of `panel.setLayout(null);` and start making use of appropriate layout managers and compound layouts. Start by having look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: I've tried that. I think someone else suggested that from another post, but when I tried that, it just took away the JTextArea completely from the panel.

Comment: Get rid of `panel.setLayout(null);`

Comment: Is that the only solution to the problem? I want to see is there is a way to do this while still keeping the null layout.

Comment: That's the preferred, long term, won't continue to screw up on you, solution. Swing (and most modern GUI frameworks) rely on some kind of automated layout mechanism, this solves a large number of issues related to DPI, font rendering, variable screen sizes and other issues

Comment: I wish I could do that, but there isn't any layout manager that I could use that would ideally perfect the visualization of my program :(

Comment: @Pvo I find the extremely unlikely - given the number of complex UI's which have been created by myself and other developers using Swing - if one layout manager won't do, then use multiple containers, utilising a combination of layouts. Consider investigating something like MigLayout. If you truely can't find one or more layout managers which do your job, then consider writing your own - the long run, they will save you more time and headaches then doing with out